# Can a DeferredToThread deferred be cancelled during a socket call?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, twisted

In my code I have setup a deferred using DeferredToThread, as, in the background I want to be able to make a socket call. However, I have noticed that if the deferred thread setup is busy with a socket call, it does not respond to a cancel() call until the socket call finishes.

It is important to mention that I do not have direct access to the code where the socket call is actually being made, hence the use of DeferredToThread.

Is there a way to forcefully stop that thread or stop that socket call? Or is there actually something else happening that I don't understand?

Comment: Unfortunately threads cannot be stopped. It's assumed that the thread will eventually come to a stop on it's own. I *think* you should be able to kill a process via the `multiprocessing` module but not with Twisted `spawnProcess` call.

Comment: Did you know Twisted has built-in support for doing socket I/O without using threads at all?

Comment: Yes, I do, but unfortunately, I don't have access to the code where the socket call is actually being made. I am trying to use Twisted with the boto3 API, so without rewriting the library, I won't be able to have more control over the socket call.